# Python dictionary to sorted tuples, can this be done better?

Tags: python, sorting, generator, iterable, dictionary

I have an dictonary for my input with the following characteristics:

- Each value will be either an integer, string or iterable (other than a string).
- If the element is an iterable, each element in that iterable will only be a string or integer.

ex:

```
mydict = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': '23',
    'three': 3,
    'four': [
        7,
        '6',
        5,
        8
    ],
    'nine': 9
}
```

I need to convert the input to a list of tuples where each tuple is a key/value pair. For iterable elements, there will be a key/value pair for each of its elements, sorted by value. For example, output for the above should be:

```
('four', 5)
('four', 7)
('four', 8)
('four', '6')
('nine', 9)
('one', 1)
('three', 3)
('two', '2')
```

I currently have this implemented using the following generator:

```
def dict_to_sorted_tuples(unsorted_dict):
    for key in sorted(unsorted_dict):
        if isinstance(unsorted_dict[key], basestring):
            yield key, unsorted_dict[key]
            continue
        try:
            for v in sorted(unsorted_dict[key]):
                yield key, v
        except:
            yield key, unsorted_dict[key]

print list(dict_to_sorted_tuples(mydict))
```

I feel this can be done in a cleaner fashion, any suggestions for improvements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> sorted((i,k) for i,j in mydict.items() for k in ([j] if isinstance(j, str) or isinstance(j, int) else j))
[('four', 5), ('four', 7), ('four', 8), ('four', '6'), ('nine', 9), ('one', 1), ('three', 3), ('two', '2')]
```

The idea here is that if the value is an `int` or a `str`, you put it in a `list`. Now the problem is simplified because you have a value you can always iterate over

If you are really sure you only need to check for `int` or `str` (not subclasses or unicode), you could just use

```
sorted((i,k) for i,j in mydict.items() for k in ([j] if type(j) in (int, str) else j))
```

If the value can be unicode, you should use `isinstance(j, basestring)` instead of `isinstance(j, str)`

Comment: You sure do know how to turn something into a one-liner! :) +1

Comment: @Trufa In this instance, I would suggest not doing it in one line. At the very least, if left as-is this should prompt a multi-line comment explaining what it does for whoever has to come along and maintain it. Clever and expressive, but requires explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
for values in sorted(mydict.items()):
    if isinstance(values[1], list):
        for x in sorted(values[1]):
            print (values[0], x,)
    else:
        print values
```

Comment: So there are no iterables other than lists? Plus, I would find `for key, value in sorted(mydict.items())` to be much more readable, as you don't need to use `values[0]` and `values[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_to_sorted_tuples(unsorted_dict):
    res = []
    for k, v in sorted(unsorted_dict.iteritems()):
        if isinstance(v, (list, tuple)):
            res.extend((k, _v) for _v in sorted(v))
        else:
            res.append((k, v))
    return res
```